# How can i toggle an input's style to look like a label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Ive got some input fields which i want to style to initially look like labels, and then via angular.js apply a style to them so they can be edited after button is pressed. I'm using bootstrap, is there a inbuilt class i can toggle on and off these inputs?

Answer (score 30):

```css
<style type="text/css">.asd {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<input type="text" class="asd" value="Label look like" disabled/>
```

Comment: +1, and I would recommend `border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)` instead of none so when the OP switches between label-style and input-style, the positioning of the text doesn't shift due to the change in border.

Comment: Instead of `rgba(0,0,0,0)` you should use `transparent` (for both `border` and `background-color`). It's slightly cheaper for rendering (not that it matters, it's more out of principle). Besides, it should be `background-color: transparent`, not `background`. `background` overrides more than just `background-color` and if any of the other props are set with a less specific selector, by other CSS declarations, they will be overridden (lost).

Answer (score 0):

Not as easy as toggling a class, but you could use a `<p>` with the `.form-control-static` class for a label, and a normal input field. Then switch visibility on those for editing.